# Unable to load css file in codeignite 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am working on Codeigniter version "4" , And i am trying to load/include css in "view" file but failed, In my "Config/app.php" file here is my base url

```
public string $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/';
```

And in view file,Here is my current code

```
 <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/frontend/css/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

And if i use following url for display css code then showing "404 not found"

```
http://localhost:8080/assets/frontend/css/style.css
```

Comment: Please confirm if your this folder structure ```assets/frontend/css/style.css```  is in public folder

Comment: What do you see in the browser when you type in `http://localhost:8080/`

Answer (score 0):

you should set url of your aaplication to your $baseurl like $baseurl = 'http://localhost/PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT' (if it is in xampp).

And Another one is you have to add the public because all the css files are in public directory like

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('public/assets/frontend/css/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```